# Show that $\Delta|\overrightarrow{n}|^2\geq 0 , \forall \overrightarrow{n}\in R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Show that $\Delta|\overrightarrow{n}|^2\geq 0 , \forall \overrightarrow{n}\in R^k$?

I feel it's right ,but I'm not sure.How to show it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec{n}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)$, then  $|\vec{n}|^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_m^2$ and
$$\Delta |\vec{n}|^2=2 m>0$$

However this won't be true for $\vec{n}$ a vector function, i.e.
$\vec{n}({\bf x})=(f_1({\bf x}),f_2({\bf x}),...,f_m({\bf x}))$, ${\bf x}\in\mathbb{R}^k$. In this case
$$\Delta|\vec{n}|^2=\Delta(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n})=\sum_i \partial_i^2(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{n})
=\sum_i \partial_i(2(\partial_i\vec{n})\cdot\vec{n})
=2\sum_i ((\partial_i^2\vec{n})\cdot\vec{n}+|\partial_i\vec{n}|^2)
$$
which does not necessarily a positive function - see the following counter example.

**Counter example**

Let $\vec{n}=(\sin x, \cos y)$, then 
$$\begin{align}
u(x,y)=\frac{1}2\Delta|\vec{n}|^2&=(-\sin x, 0)\cdot(\sin x, \cos y)+
|(\cos x,0)|^2\\
&+
(0, -\cos y)\cdot(\sin x, \cos y)+
|(0,-\sin y)|^2\\
&=-\sin^2 x+\cos^2x-\cos^2y+\sin^2y
\end{align}$$
isn't non negative, for example $u(\frac{\pi}2,0)=-2$.

Note, you can also differentiate $|\vec{n}|^2=\sin^2 x +\cos^2 y$ straight forward to get the same result.

Comment: It seems to me that $\vec n$ is not any function, it's $|\vec n|^2 = x_1^2 + \cdots x_m^2$.

Comment: what's wrong? $|(\sin(x),\cos y)|^2=\sin^2 x+\cos^2 y$

Comment: I mean, $\vec n \in \mathbb R^m$, so $|\vec n|^2$ is really **the** function $\vec n =(x_1, \cdots, x_m)\mapsto x_1^2 + \cdots x_m^2$ on $\mathbb R^m$. (that is, just that $r^2$ from the polar coordinate)

Comment: If so it is become too simple. In this case $\Delta |\vec{n}|^2=2 m$, for example
$|\vec {n}(x,y,z)|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$, $\Delta |\vec{n}|^2=2\cdot 3=6$

Comment: Yes, it is simple. But it is up to the OP to clarify.